# Need to change label text during OnClick event. ASP pages with C# backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, multithreading, web-applications

I have a web application using ASP pages and C# backend. I have a button that triggers a very long method. In this method, about 20 functions are called, ranging from deleting tables, executing procedures and loading excel spreadsheets. In everyone of these function calls (that are run via the button OnClick event), It will change the text of a label (a status indicator to the user) and possibly trigger an AJAX ModalPopupExtender with a warning message when something fails. The Label change and the Popup extender will not trigger within the OnCLick event. I believe it is because of the single OnClick thread that is running all these actions. If it was a Windows Forms app, I could use Update() to force the label change.

I believe the solution involves multithreading but am not sure where to begin. Any help would be appreciated. Would the OnClick event be the main thread and the underlying functions the second thread?

Comment: Easiest way would be to create an ajax call for everything you call that´s supposed to change the labels on completion. So you would have to break your method down into smaller pieces that return sooner, change the text, then call the next method with another ajax in the complete callback of the first and so forth. Otherwise you would have to do some long polling or use web sockets to be able to notify the client when to update the label.

Comment: Can you give me a code example? Other that the single line call for the popup, I am not sure how to do ajax calls. Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

> Can you give me a code example? Other that the single line call for the popup, I am not sure how to do ajax calls. Thank You !

Here you go.

```
function onClickButton() {
    getPartOne();
}

function getPartOne() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://yourapp/api/doPartOne", //'@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")' if you´re in a razor file you can use Url.Action
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (returnData) {
            //do something on success
            $('#myLabel').text(returnData.someProperty);
        },
        error: function() {
            //do something if it fails
        },
        complete: function (returnData) {
            //do something on completion regardless of success or fail
            getPartTwo(); //call next ajax
        }
    });
}

function getPartTwo() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://yourapp/api/doPartTwo",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (returnData) {
            //do something on success
        }
    });
}
```

Also have a look at ([jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

This won´t work without jquery. But you probably have jquery as it comes with asp.net net projects by default. If you don´t either use [XmlHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) built into javascript or include jquery.

Comment: Thanks. So this looks like a Javascript solution that would go on the ASP page and call methods on the C# page, is that correct? If so, you have it written for a MVC project. Mine is a straight up C# page (no MVC). How would I call a method from the code behind in this way ?  Thanks, Eric

Comment: Not quite. The javascript runs on your clients browser, while Asp.Net (C#) runs on your server. So you're can't "just call the method", but it sends a http request to your server and the url maps to your function. ```@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")``` is the piece of razor (c#) code that generates the URL that maps to your c# function (action) in your controller. I've never used asp.net without mvc before. You gotta have some kind of URL mapping (routing) and that's what you should use as url. I don't think a 100% c# solution is even possible unless you're getting into Blazor(WebAssembly).

Comment: What about creating another thread to run the functions? If I creating a separate thread off the OnClick event button to run the 20 odd functions and allow the OnClick thread to complete, wouldn't the ASP page then respond to the Label text changes and popup window requests?

Comment: Short awnswer would be no you can´t, or should not try. Long awnswer possible, but resulting in comparison very unuseable solution, since c# does not run in the browser you would have to reload the entier page. And since the client does not really know when to refresh the page you would then probably end up refreshing the page every second just to update the label every 20 seconds.

There is a good reason they ship jquery with asp.net and it´s surely not because you can do everything with c#. You absolutely need javascript exactly because you can´t just "change a thing" on the page otherwise